# Ajax ToolKit Tabpanel Error

Tags: asp.net, tabpanel

I´m working with visual studio 2005 and ajaxtoolkit 2.0 .

I´m using ajaxtoolkit Tabpanel control in a webpage. I have one Tab for adding data, and i built dymanically other Tabs for loading data (DB) and update.

The Tab of adding data, does not give me any problem, since the controls are put in the page from the beginning. But the controls of the dynamic Tabs doesn´t work, doesn´t retrieve the data in a postback.
The Tabs are created in the Init event, and this is a second problem because i need the viewstate data for making the update Tabs. I Know that controls have to be created in the Init Event, so i did it, but the problem is still here.

I think is a bug control.

Does Anyone a solution for Dynamic Tabs?

Thank You,
and Sorry , for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your tab creation in the on_load (even on postback)